# "This" not refering to current object

Tags: javascript, this

I am kind of new to OOP in JS. I would like to know why when creating sub-objects, this stops referring to the main object AFTER the second level of subobjects.

```
function Clase()
{
    this.__construct = function()
    {
    this.paginator();            
    alert('__construct finished');
    };                

    this.paginator = function()
    {

        this.paginator.title = function()
        {
            this.paginator.title.set_offsets  = function()
            {
                alert('paginator.title.set_offsets executed!');

            };
        };

        this.paginator.title(); //instantiating

        alert('subobject paginator created');            
     };

    this.__construct();
}

var instancia = new Clase();

instancia.paginator.title.set_offsets();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WYWwE/

The error is: this.paginator is undefined.

And now, if I use closures, it works perfectly:

```
function Clase()
{
    self = this;

    this.__construct = function()
    {
        this.paginator();            
        alert('__construct finished');
    };                

    this.paginator = function()
    {

        self.paginator.title = function()
        {
            self.paginator.title.set_offsets  = function()
            {
                alert('instancia.paginator.title.set_offsets() executed');

            };
     };
     self.paginator.title();

     alert('this.paginator created');
};

this.__construct();
}

var instancia = new Clase();

instancia.paginator.title.set_offsets();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/esjHu/

So, AFAIK after some point, "this" stops refering to the class "Clase" and refers to something else. If so, is it a good practice to use closures this way?

Is it also correct to start the class with self = this; and from then on use ONLY "self"? for instance: http://jsfiddle.net/byGRX/

Comment: 'This' can change based on the context you're in. A similar question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword), and the first response links to a good article on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, the link was interesting, but it does not answer my question. I still don't know why 'this' is lost when I go down in the object layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lose the reference to the "original" `this` when you nest `function`s. To remedy do the following:

```
function Clase() {
    var that = this;


    this.paginator = {

        title: {

            set_offsets: function() {
                alert('paginator.title.set_offsets executed!');

            }
        }
    };
};

var foo = new Clase();

foo.paginator.title.set_offsets();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vd5YK/

Comment: Thanks, it works. But is it possible to do it using constructor notation? I would prefer to stick to one style. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok I give up, I move back to the literal notation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't lose reference to the `this` object, here's what happens:

For example:

```
function Class() {

  this.func1 = function () {

    this.func1.func2 = function () {
      alert('Works!');
    };

  };

  this.func1.func2();
}

x = new Class();
```

Now, the reason you get an error saying that `func2` doesn't exist is because the function object for `func2` isn't constructed until you call `func1`:

```
function Class() {

  this.func1 = function () {

    this.func1.func2 = function () {
      alert('Works!');
    };

  };

  this.func1();
  this.func1.func2();
}

x = new Class();
```

And now it works.

**EDIT:**

So, why doesn't this work:

```
function Class() {

    this.func1 = function() {

        this.func1.func2 = function() {

            this.func1.func2.func3 = function() {
                alert('works!');
            };

            this.func1.func2.property = 5;
        };

    };

    this.func1();
    this.func1.func2();
}

x = new Class();

x.func1.func2.func3();
```

Basically, what your trying to do is add a property named `property` and a method named `func3` to the function object of `func2`, but the problem is that `func2` isn't constructed before calling `func1`. It's the same as doing:

```
function Class() {

    this.func1 = function() {

        this.func1.func2 = function() {};

    };

    this.func1.func2.func3 = function() {
        alert('works!');
    };
    this.func1.func2.property = 5;

    this.func1();
    this.func1.func2();
}

x = new Class();

x.func1.func2.func3();
```

If you want it to work you need first construct the function object for `func2` by calling `func1`:

```
function Class() {

    this.func1 = function() {

        this.func1.func2 = function() {};

    };

    this.func1();

    this.func1.func2.func3 = function() {
        alert('works!');
    };
    this.func1.func2.property = 5;

    // this.func1.func2();

}

x = new Class();

x.func1.func2.func3();
alert(x.func1.func2.property);
```

Comment: Hi,

That also works for me. The problem comes when I want to create another sublevel of objects. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SwNPs/

As long as I use this. I lose the reference to the object from the 2nd level on.

Thanks anyway!!

Comment: @ikaros45 I've extended my answer.

Comment: Good explanation Korikulum, but the code turns out to be too messy. I'm going for Xander's solution. I really don't love literal notation but code is much cleaner and simple.

Thank you!